# Writing string with ANSI escape sequences to file

Tags: python, bash, ansi-escape

A python module I am using provides a hook that allows capturing user keyboard input before it is sent to a shell terminal. The problem I am facing is that it captures input character-by-character, which makes capturing the input commands difficult when the user performs such things as backspacing or moving the cursor.

For example, given the string **exit\x1b[4D\x1b[Jshow myself out**, the following takes place:

```
>>> a = exit\x1b[4D\x1b[Jshow myself out
>>> print(a)
show myself out

>>> with open('file.txt', 'w+') as f:
>>>     f.write(a)
>>> exit()
less abc.txt
```

The less command shows the raw command (exit\x1b[4D\x1b[Jshow myself out), when in fact I would like it to be stored 'cleanly' as it is displayed when using the print function (show myself out).

Printing the result, or 'cat'ing the file shows exactly what I would want to be displayed, but I am guessing here that the terminal is transforming the output.

Is there a way to achieve a 'clean' write to file, either using some python module, or some bash utility? Surely there must be some module out there that can do this for me?

Comment: You have two options here: (1) write or find a library that interprets ANSI sequences and transforms strings after the fact, or (2) stop capturing character by character and instead use line buffering (ideally with `readline`) and get the transformed data in the first place. The second one isn't always appropriate, but when it is, it's a whole lot simpler.

Comment: Meanwhile, if what you're asking for is a library or utility that does #1, that's not a bad question, but it's a bad fit for SO. It _may_ be a good fit for [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but since I don't frequent that site, don't quote me on that.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the distinction between SO and Software Recs. I may continue my search there if I don't make any progress tonight. In regards to your first comment, unfortunately the module I am using does not allow for that, so I am under the impression that I am to find a utility that will do the ANSI interpretation for me (so far [ansiterm](https://github.com/helgefmi/ansiterm) seems to have what I need).

Comment: Whatever solution you use one problem you are going to have is that in all likelihood the word `exit` won't be filtered out. That is straight up text that happens to be hidden by the terminal software  (it is printed even when you ran it in Python but the escape sequences overwrote that area of the screen). The best I could find was this: `perl -pe  's/\e\[[\d,\s]*[a-zA-Z]//g; s/\e\][\d];//g; s/\r\n/\n/g; s/[
+\000-\011]//g; s/[\013-\037]//g' <file.txt >newfile.txt`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: It wouldn't be _hard_ to write what is, in effect, a headless ANSI terminal emulator that can take input with control sequences and produce the equivalent output, which means that the word `exit` _would_ be filtered out, exactly because it's hidden by the terminal. But it certainly would be _tedious_, and if someone's already done it (which I hope is a Software Recs question, but I can't promise that it is…) it makes perfect sense for the asker to take advantage of that.

Comment: Actually, now that I write it in those terms… instead of a headless ANSI terminal emulator, is it possible to write a headless ANSI terminal driver? For example, create a PTY, put in line-buffered mode with `readline`, feed the user's input into it, and pull lines out of it? That might be harder, but less tedious, and a lot more robust (unless it's completely untenable). I have to think about this more… unless someone else can tell me why it's obviously wrong (or that it's easy and has already been done).

Comment: The unix utility `col` does something like that, but it doesn't understand VT-100 codes afaik. I believe an updated version which does understand them exists.

Comment: @rici: `col` works if you've already translated your terminal codes to backspaces and CRs… but doing that first step seems just as hard as doing the whole thing. But looking for an updated version of `col` does seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

`less` is interpreting the control characters.

You can get around this with the `-r` command line option:

```
$ less -r file.txt 
show myself out
```

From the manual:

```
   -r or --raw-control-chars
          Causes "raw" control characters to be displayed.  The default is
          to display control characters  using  the  caret  notation;  for
          example, a control-A (octal 001) is displayed as "^A".  Warning:
          when the -r option is used, less cannot keep track of the actual
          appearance  of  the screen (since this depends on how the screen
          responds to each type of control character).  Thus, various dis‐
          play  problems may result, such as long lines being split in the
          wrong place.
```

The raw control characters are sent to the terminal, which then interprets them as `cat` would.

As others have stated, you would need to interpret the characters yourself before writing them to a file.